# Arrival on suvarnabhumi airport at midnight 00.30am.My next flight is 8.30am

Tags: indian-citizens

I will arrival at suvarnabhumi airport bangkok by 00.30am (midnight) my next flight is at 8.30am. During these hours, if any places is worth to visit between the 00.30am to 8.30am near by suvarnabhumi airport. and also please advise me about transportation.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately recommending places worth visiting is off topic on this site. Please read our help centre to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing much at that time of night in Lat Krabang (the city nearby the airport). Time is probably better spent picking up a cheap (400 baht on up) hotel room and catch a few hours sleep.  This of course assumes you are entering Thailand and the morning flight is a domestic one.

If you are connecting to another international flight, then you are better off staying airside and saving the 1000 baht VOA fee. Lots of benches on the 3rd floor for napping between flights.